# How can you get database specific performance metrics for things like CPU/Memory/etc. in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance, optimization

I have a couple databases on a shared SQL Server 2005 cluster instance, that I would like performance metrics on. I have some processes that run for a very long time and suspect that code inefficiencies, rather than insufficient hardware are to blame.

I would like some way to get these performance metrics so that I can rule out the database hardware as the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

That's tricky... you can use performance monitor to track hardware and OS factors - like CPU usage, memory; and also various SQL Server counters like queries per second. Obviously memory usage would tell you if you need more RAM, but it's not so easy to tell if (say) high CPU usage is due to the inefficient code, or just intensive code.

Some of the counters are more helpful to drilling down into performance issues - things like locks in the DB can be counted, the problem is you cannot tell how many is too many because all code works differently. You can tell if you're experiencing far too many, or if periods of slowness equate to large counts. This applies to various of the other counters too - go and have a look what there is to view.

The other thing to do is run a trace (sql server tools) to get a list of the queries that are run. Take a few of the slowest/biggest and see what execution plans come out when you run them - this would suggest you might optimise the queries, though it's down to you to decide if the code is inefficient or just as intensive as before.

Lastly, get a tool like Spotlight that rolls a lot of database stats up and displays them to you in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I just read a great article on using windows built in typeperf.exe for just this issue.  http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1575

Answer (score 1):

Ah, sounds like a job for SQL Profiler. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: This looks like a good tool. Almost there... I still can't figure how to limit to just one specific Database, however.